# Aligning submenus in a VGroup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, layout

I'm trying to set up a pretty simple menu/submenu system in Flex - the kind you'd see on a website. I've done this in pure Actionscript before but now that I'm working with Flex I'm stuck trying to get the submenus to align to the right and grow out of the left side of a group. I want to prevent the menu for the far right button from bleeding off the side of the screen.

Left Aligned Menu (Current, desired behavior: The left side of the menu aligns with the left side of the button)
[image]

Right Aligned Menu (Current, undesired behavior: The left side of the menu aligns with the left side of the button)
[image]

Right Aligned Menu (Desired behavior: The right side of the menu aligns with the right side of the button)
[image]

Each "ComboButton" object contains a VGroup containing the button and menu components.

```
<s:VGroup gap="0">
    <components:BarButtonComponent id="button" />
    <components:BarButtonMenuComponent id="menu" />
</s:VGroup>
```

The ComboButton object overrides `measuredWidth` and `measuredHeight` to return the dimensions of the only BarButtonComponent. I'm not sure how to proceed here. I tried using a nested HGroup around the menu and setting `horizontalAlign="right"` but that didn't do anything because that HGroup's width just becomes the width of what's inside it.

Comment: hard to help without seeing more of the code

Comment: @Chris Here's the ComboButton class: https://github.com/olinkirkland/omg-client/blob/master/src/components/BarButtonComboComponent.mxml and the rest of the code is open source on GH.

Comment: But the Bar and Menu could be anything. Replace them with plain rectangles of different sizes like in my illustrations and you get the same result.

Comment: I would use PopUpAnchor component from the framework to implement the menu. It has an option to positioning left, right etc. and won't interfere with the layout/dimensions of your button.

Comment: So there's no option that allows for "proper" right-align logic in VGroups, with objects pushing out in the left direction and the anchor point being the top right?

Comment: Have you tried: VGroup with two HGroup, each with 100% width. Apply the right-align inside each HGroup.

Comment: That pushes the "button 2" off screen because the "button 2 menu" grows offscreen anyway